# getBoolean returning false

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a program that needs to check for default preference settings and respond accordingly. The getBoolean method is always returning false even though R.xml.preferences has defaultValues set as true. I've tested
`preferences.contains(prefKey)` 
and this has returned true.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);

    populate();

}

public void populate() {
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

  try {
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
      if (preferences.getBoolean(prefKey, false)){
        for (int max = 0; max < 20; max++) {
          System.out.println("this ran"+ max + "times at" + i);
        }
      } else {
        for (int max = 0; max < 20; max++) {
          System.out.println("this Skipped"+ max + "times at" + i);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException ioe) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your prefs (in onCreate), before setting defaults:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().clear().commit();
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);
```

From the [PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean)) documentation:

> Note: this will NOT reset preferences back to their default values.
>   For that functionality, use getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) and
>   clear it followed by a call to this method with this parameter set to
>   true.

Comment: This worked, any chance you could explain the reasoning behind this? As well as setting the readAgain to true?

Comment: @shores, I can't speak for whoever designed this class/method, but my guess is that it has to do with initializing defaults (first time) vs resetting defaults (subsequently). Also, seems to do with whether defaults should overwrite existing or simply "fill-in" empty keys. Either way, the docs say to do it this way, so we just need to follow what they say. Also, if my answer worked, please up-vote and accept as correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this

```
 if (preferences.getBoolean(prefKey, false))//your default value here is false
```

change to

```
if (preferences.getBoolean(prefKey, true))
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. They're getting false when the key apparently exists already. They don't want the default to be true.

Comment: Yeah changing it to true still seems to result in a false so i'm guessing that indicates it's not reading the preference.xml file correctly

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have called `setDefaultValues` previously set *prefKey* to false.  According to the [PreferenceManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29)

> Note: this will NOT reset preferences back to their default values. For that functionality, use getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) and clear it followed by a call to this method with this parameter set to true.